# Override a block from an include via extend is blank?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-1.4

So I have a base template, which includes a header:

**base.html**:

```
{% include "header.html" %}
```

**header.html**:

```
<ul>
     <li><a>Link</a></li>
     <li><a>Link</a></li>
     <li><a>Link</a></li>
</ul>
{% block diskspace %}Test{% endblock %}
```

Then I would like to override the `diskspace` block from a template which extends the base, for instance:

**album.html**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block diskspace %}
<p>You need more space!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately however `diskspace` only contains "Test" and is not overridden.

Is what I'm attempting possible, or do I need to go another route?

**SOLUTION**

Based on sergzach's answer below, here's what I ultimately implemented:

**header.html:**

```
<ul>
     <li><a>Link</a></li>
     <li><a>Link</a></li>
     <li><a>Link</a></li>
</ul>
{% if show_diskspace %}
    <p>You need more space!</p>
{% endif %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% block header %}
    {% include "header.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**album.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header %}
    {% include "header.html" with show_diskspace="True" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Would you like to replace "Test" or to append something?

Comment: Replace. Technically the block should be empty, I just have "Test" there so I know whether any action is being taken on the block at all.

Comment: The blocks in included templates can't be overriden in templates which include them.

Comment: Ahh yes it seems to be that way, guess I'll try another route, thanks for trying :)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please look at that.

Comment: Ultimately the answer I landed on is not ideal given that I'd like to keep the diskspace HTML in the album.html template really, however it'll do fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**header.html**:

```
    <ul>
         <li><a>Link</a></li>
         <li><a>Link</a></li>
         <li><a>Link</a></li>
    </ul>

{{diskspace}}
```

**base.html**

```
{% block header %}
    {% include "header.html" with diskspace='Test'%}
{% endblock %}
```

**album.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header %}
    {% include "header.html" with diskspace='<p>You need more space!</p>'|safe %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ahh well, the diskspace is intended to contain much more complex HTML, however your answer did finally get me to where I need. I'll update the question to reflect my solution. Thanks

Comment: @DanH You can place all variants of html into header.html and pass it not a html string but identifier of a current option.